# How can I upgrade only the apache2 package on Debian 9?

Tags: debian

In Debian Stretch there is `apache2` version 2.4.25-3 but I need at least 2.4.26 (for [`ProxyFCGISetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#proxyfcgisetenvif)). I am not a pro in Debian, and don't know the right way to do this... I also tried to find a repository with the latest `apache2` - no luck.

Upgrading to Debian Sid does not seems not very right. Maybe someone can tell me how I can get the latest Apache 2.4 in Debian Stretch?

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to build the newer Apache packages from source, using the Buster source package. This involves building a few extra build dependencies. You’ll end up with a clean installation of the web server, using Debian packages, which will be automatically upgraded to the Buster versions once you upgrade to that. In the mean time, you will have to keep track of any security updates to the Buster packages and rebuild them yourself.

Start by installing some useful packages:

```
sudo apt install build-essential devscripts
```

Enable Stretch backports, which we’ll need for one package:

```
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
sudo apt update
```

Build `libapr`:

```
cd /tmp
dget -x http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apr/apr_1.6.5-1.dsc
dpkg-source -x apr_1.6.5-1.dsc
cd apr-1.6.5
mk-build-deps debian/control
sudo apt install ./apr-build-deps_1.6.5-1_amd64.deb
mv ./apr-build-deps_1.6.5-1_amd64.deb ..
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

Install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../libapr1_1.6.5-1_amd64.deb ../libapr1-dev_1.6.5-1_amd64.deb
```

Build `libssl`:

```
cd /tmp
dget -x http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1a-1.dsc
dpkg-source -x openssl_1.1.1a-1.dsc
cd openssl-1.1.1a
mk-build-deps debian/control
sudo apt install ./openssl-build-deps_1.1.1a-1_all.deb
mv ./openssl-build-deps_1.1.1a-1_all.deb ..
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

Install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../libssl-dev_1.1.1a-1_amd64.deb ../libssl1.1_1.1.1a-1_amd64.deb
```

Build `apr-util`:

```
cd /tmp
dget -x http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apr-util/apr-util_1.6.1-3.dsc
dpkg-source -x apr-util_1.6.1-3.dsc
cd apr-util-1.6.1
mk-build-deps debian/control
sudo apt install ./apr-util-build-deps_1.6.1-3_all.deb
mv ./apr-util-build-deps_1.6.1-3_all.deb ..
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

Install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../libaprutil1-dev_1.6.1-3_amd64.deb ../libaprutil1_1.6.1-3_amd64.deb
```

Build `apache2`:

```
cd /tmp
dget -x http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.38-2.dsc
dpkg-source -x apache2_2.4.38-2.dsc
cd apache2-2.4.38
mk-build-deps debian/control
sudo apt install ./apache2-build-deps_2.4.38-2_all.deb
```

(This might fail if you have other `libaprutil` packages installed; upgrade them by installing the corresponding packages built previously.)

```
mv ./apache2-build-deps_2.4.38-2_all.deb ..
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

Finally, install whichever Apache packages you need among those that were built in the last step.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use pinning as suggested in https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing?

Comment: @StrongBad because pulling in `apache2` from Buster on a Sarge system ends up upgrading many packages to Buster, including `libc6` and any package depending on `libcurl`.

Comment: Doesn't that imply that one of the dependencies is wrong somewhere in the Debian package tree?

Comment: No, it implies that Stretch (not Sarge as I wrote above, sorry) and Buster are different releases, and most packages in Buster were built with newer packages than those in Stretch, and many end up with dependencies which aren’t satisfiable in Stretch.

Answer (score -2):

```
echo 'deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/testing.list
apt-get update
apt-get source apache2
apt-get build-dep apache2
cd apache2-*
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc
apt install ../*apache*deb
```

If you notice any unmet dependencies with `build-dep`, then repeat the same commands for this package, install it, then try again.

Comment: Sorry for editing, wrong button pressed.

Comment: Ignore this, you’ll end up partially upgrading to Buster if you follow these instructions. I’m writing up a working answer for Stretch.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't like this idea. the idea to upgrade to buster is little bit better then building from sources and get unsupported package.